# Why is the answer false and not true?

Tags: c

This is more of a logic problem, there's no code to be written but even after multiple tries on this problem, I keep getting that the answer is true.

So here's the problem:

```
int cat = 5, dog = 6, cow = 2, lizard = 10
```

And I want to find the answer for this expression:
`!(!cow + !cat + !dog + !lizard)`

Here's my attempt at the solution:

I thought that by saying !cow, we are saying !5. Then, I was thinking that !5 meant that it would not be true because it's ! of an integer value, thus making !cow=0. Then I did the same for everything else inside the parentheses. Giving me: !(0) and by applying the ! operator, I get true. (Since 0 typically means that it's false right?)

Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Who says the answer should be false?

Comment: So why is your title wrong, as you found the answer *is* true?

Comment: The correct answer, said by my instructor, was false :(

Comment: This isn't code.  Don't write code like this.  If you're maintaining code that was written like this, rewrite it.

Comment: Either your instructor is incorrect, or your instructor misread the question.

Comment: @GregHewgill So, if he misread the question, he's correct?

Comment: Or OP misread the question or OP test example if flawed.

Comment: But if the question is "What's 2 + 2?" The correct answer is 4.  That's the only correct answer.  If you say 5, you're wrong.  You might be wrong because you don't know how to add, or you might be wrong because you misread it as 2 + 3, but you're still wrong...

Comment: I only make the distinction because... if my program has a bug in it, it has a bug in it.  It doesn't matter if the bug exists because I'm a bad programmer, or if it exists because Apple changed Objective-C again and a method I was using is now deprecated.  Fact of the matter is, a bug exists, and it's my responsibility to not allow bugs to exist in my code.

Answer (score 3):

You're right - your expression evaluates to `1`, that is, true.

Comment: Oh! Hmm...that's strange, my instructor said that the answer's false :(

Comment: Sometimes people make mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

```
int cat = 5, dog = 6, cow = 2, lizard = 10;
```

The value of:

```
 !(!cow + !cat + !dog + !lizard)
```

is `1`. And the value of the `true` macro from `stdbool.h` is also `1`.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm...very strange, I wonder why my instructor said that the answer's false. :(